# Meteor collection observeChanges causing infinite loop

Tags: meteor

I am trying to show a message whenever a new record is added to my collection using collection.observeChanges as shown in the code below, yet once the app is loaded the app enter in an infinite loop of showing the console message (added) as shown below, so can someone please tell me what I am missing here and how I can fix it in order to make it show the 'added' message only when a new record is added to the collection? thanks

```
Template.homePage.helpers({
  'notifications'() {
    let userNotCol = userNotCol.find({ userID: Meteor.userId(), read: false });
    userNotCol.observeChanges({
      added: function(id, fields){
        if(!fields.read){
          console.log('added'); // This enters in infinite loop 
        }
      }
    });
    return userNotCol;
  }
});
```

Comment: How many documents your cursor initially returns?

Comment: @ghybs approx. 19

Answer (score 1):

i would suggest not having the observe in the helper. helpers are meant to help the template render data. any logic should exist outside there. helpers can get called multiple times, which you may not expect.

you can set up your find() and observe() in the onCreated() of the template. if you expect the user to change while the template is active, you can wrap the find() and observe() in an autorun block.

once your added handler is called, you can set the result into a reactive var. then your helper need do nothing other than return the value in that reactive var.

Answer (score 0):

This may help clear things up. From the [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Cursor-observeChanges):

> observeChanges returns a live query handle, which is an object with a
>   stop method. Call stop with no arguments to stop calling the callback
>   functions and tear down the query. The query will run forever until
>   you call this. If observeChanges is called from a Tracker.autorun
>   computation, it is automatically stopped when the computation is rerun
>   or stopped. (If the cursor was created with the option reactive set to
>   false, it will only deliver the initial results and will not call any
>   further callbacks; it is not necessary to call stop on the handle.)

And so the issue is not an infinite loop but rather that the query will run forever - or until stop is called.